# Issue with multipart upload in servlet on seam

Tags: java, jboss, file-upload, seam, apache-commons

I created a servlet wich works fine when deployed in a separate war file, but I intend to use it as part of a seam application.

I use commons-fileupload but the iterator (see snippet) returns false (only when included in the seam-app).

Any ideas?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String action = request.getParameter( "action" );

            if ( ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent( request ) ) {
                log.info( "MULTIPART" );
            }
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator( request );
            // --------- hasNext() returns false, only in seam -----------
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
                             ......
                    }
```

Additional Info:
I don't want to use the technique described [here](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/HowToUploadAndDownloadFilesInSeam) since the uploading client is curl.

The `HttpServletRequest` is wrapped by `org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityRequestWrapper` Using the seam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to insert

```
<web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="true" 
        max-request-size="1000000" 
        url-pattern="*.seam"/>
```

into `components.xml`

[Documentation](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/seam/Seam_Reference_Guide/Seam_servlet_filters-Multipart_form_submissions.html)